# In Excel: how to highlight cells that has a sepcific character more than once

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, the following list of values are in column A

```
research.med.helsinki.fi
fixus.fi
fixusnet.fi
toolpack.fi
porinteatteri.fi
lippu.fi
ensemble.fi
autoarvio.fi
ratti.autoarvio.fi
adwords.google.com
fram.fi
edriver.fram.fi
alajarvi.perussuomalaiset.fi
per.us.su.omalaiset.fi
```

I have many more similar values in column A

I would ike to highlight all value that has the dot character (.) more than once, it can be a vba macro or a formula

After running the macro/formula the following values should be highlighted:

```
research.med.helsinki.fi
ratti.autoarvio.fi
adwords.google.com
edriver.fram.fi
alajarvi.perussuomalaiset.fi
per.us.su.omalaiset.fi
```

Thanks
Ziv

Answer (score 4):

You can use formula based conditional formatting, so `len(a1)-substitute(a1,".","")>=2`

Comment: break the formula up, in the column next to it, put the substitute bit in as a formula, see what result

Comment: @Ziv Then possibly you didn't adapt it to your data as needed.  Copy/Paste the exact formula you are using, and also the `Applies to` box from the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager`  It works properly here with the data set you show in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts with Cells A2

Run the below code. It will highlight the data that contains more than 1 dots (in Column A).

```
Sub highlight()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If (Len(Range("A" & i).Value) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Range("A" & i).Value, ".", "")) > 1) Then
            Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

[image]